# SUPEE-6285 - Failed - Magento 1.9.3.8 - Magento Scanner

Tags: magento-1.9.3.8, supee-6285

I've got problem with Magento Scanner - i've got just one error with:

```
SUPEE-6285 - Failed.
Access to /downloader/Maged/ should be restricted (APPSEC-847), got '500'.
Access to /downloader/lib/ should be restricted (APPSEC-847), got '500'.
```

I've got .htaccess files with:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

How i can remove this message from scanner to get "You're site is secure"?

Comment: The message is telling you that your server is responding to security checks on those folders with a status 500 Internal Server Error. The Magento Scanner is probably expecting the server to return a 403 Forbidden error. That means there is something misconfigured on your server, and checking your server's error logs will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ah thanks friend! 

Apache 2.4 i've got and htaccess is created for 2.2.